# mysql order by multiple column optimization

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I'm trying to learn the 'order by optimization' of mysql, so i search the related topic and find the official [doc of mysql8](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/order-by-optimization.html) says :

> A condition for index use is that the index must have the same homogeneity, but need not have the same actual direction.

> If a query mixes ASC and DESC, the optimizer can use an index on the columns if the index also uses corresponding mixed ascending and descending columns:

```sql
SELECT * FROM t1
  ORDER BY key_part1 DESC, key_part2 ASC;
```

> The optimizer can use an index on (key_part1, key_part2) if key_part1 is descending and key_part2 is ascending. It can also use an index on those columns (with a backward scan) if key_part1 is ascending and key_part2 is descending.

When creating a multiple column index, take (key_part1, key_part2) for example, we **can't** specify the order for key_part1 and key_part2,  when we execute the query above, **how optimizer can know that the index have the same homogeneity or not?**

According to the doc ,the counter intuitive is that even if we use different sort order for two columns(key_part1 desc and the key_part2 asc) when querying, mysql optimizer may still make use the index if the index have the same homogeneity 。

I searched everywhere but can't find the answer, i hope a further detailed explanation.

Comment: MySQL 8.0 honors the directions given in the `INDEX`; before that, the index was silently changed to all ASC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> we can't specify the order for key_part1 and key_part2

You can do something like the following to create a multiple column index with different sort orders:

```
CREATE INDEX idx ON table (col1 asc, col2 desc);
```

From https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-index.html:

> An index specification of the form (key_part1, key_part2, ...) creates
> an index with multiple key parts. Index key values are formed by
> concatenating the values of the given key parts. For example (col1,
> col2, col3) specifies a multiple-column index with index keys
> consisting of values from col1, col2, and col3.
>
> A key_part specification can end with ASC or DESC to specify whether
> index values are stored in ascending or descending order.

Comment: can you give me a link

Comment: Updated with a link and a quote from the doc.